# How to change placeholder text

Tags: jquery, attributes, placeholder

I am trying to change the placeholder text on click event but its not working. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#HitMe', function() {
  $('#SessionId').attr('placeholder', "changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="SessionId" type="text" value="" placeholder="Please Enter Session ID">
<input id="HitMe" type="text" placeholder="HitME">
```

Comment: It's working as expected

Comment: placeholder text or the text on the input field ?

Comment: Seems to work fine.
https://plnkr.co/edit/oc0kdwVuAg26TT4fZaie?p=preview

Comment: I put the code you provided in to a snippet, and you can see it works absolutely fine. If you still have issues in your site, check the console for errors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok so it doesn't change the placeholder when there is something typed on SessionId textbox. Can we not add placeholder when a textbox contains a value?

Comment: No. The whole point of a placeholder is to be shown when there is no value. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with a placeholder when the input does have a value...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually I want to append an error message on this textbox and when the user clicks it, will add a placeholder

Comment: But again - why a placeholder? It won't be seen unless the input is empty, and the value will never be sent with the form data, so it seems a little pointless

Answer (score 1):

It is working perfectly,

Please Check these two points.

1. When there is text entered in the `SessionId`  input field you wont be able to see the place holder text
2. Check if you have included the jquery library

```js
$(document).on('click', '#HitMe', function() {
  $('#SessionId').attr('placeholder', "changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="SessionId" type="text" value="" placeholder="Please Enter Session ID">
<input id="HitMe" type="text" placeholder="HitME">
```